# Nested classes and static method

Tags: python, class

I have this code:

```
class Servicer(object):
    clsVrb = "run"

    class SrvOne(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    class SrvTwo(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def make_SrvOne(name):
        return SrvOne(name)





test = Servicer.make_SrvOne("Edgar")
print test
```

But I get an exception that SrvOne is undefined. How can it be undefined? Why doesn't `Servicer` see `SrvOne`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's defined in the `Servicer` namespace, there's no local `SrvOne` in `make_SrvOne` and there is no global `SrvOne`.

```
@staticmethod
def make_SrvOne(name):
    return Servicer.SrvOne(name)
```

Why isn't Servicer just a module?

Comment: Thanks. Right, probably should just be a module.